# npm having error resolving react-i18nextjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to install the package react-i18next using npm install but I am having trouble.
I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @ant-design/icons@4.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/icons
npm ERR!     @ant-design/icons@"^4.7.0" from antd@4.20.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/antd
npm ERR!       antd@"^4.20.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.9.0" from @ant-design/react-slick@0.28.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/react-slick
npm ERR!     @ant-design/react-slick@"~0.28.1" from antd@4.20.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/antd
npm ERR!       antd@"^4.20.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   54 more (@emotion/react, @react-google-maps/api, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!   react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!     react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
```

I tried to do npm update npm install but it did not work I am getting the same error. I am not sure what's the issue here.

my react version is 17.0.2 for the project is this the source of the error? If I try to force the installation would this cause more error?

Answer (score 0):

you have several package that have react 16 listed as dependencies. Usually React 17 would also work since there are no real breaking changes from React 16 to 17.

so you can do npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Even better would be to first update your packages that still have react 16 as dependency

like react-reveal and antd

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, how can I update them? I just do npm package update?

Comment: first try npm update, if it doesn't help yet then install the individual packages with  @latest append. for example npm install react-reveal@latest.

It can still be though that even the latest version have an old version of react as dependency. In that case you are temporary stuck with installing with npm i --legacy-peer-deps, and you could open an issue for the library maintainers to update their dependecies